# Как посчитать общую калорийность выбранных в ListBox блюд и вывести это значение на отдельный label?

Tags: c#, framework, label, visual-studio-2019, listbox

Это код для вывода информации на форму:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Recept.Domain;

namespace Recept
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Recipe> recipes;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FillListBoxRecipe();
        }

        public void FillListBoxRecipe()
        {
            recipes = new List<Recipe>();

            recipes.Add(CompletedReceipes.FirstRecipe());
            recipes.Add(CompletedReceipes.SecondRecipe());
            recipes.Add(CompletedReceipes.ThirdRecipe());

            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                listBoxRecepts.Items.Add(recipe.Name);  
            }

            if (listBoxRecepts.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem = listBoxRecepts.Items[0];
            }
        }

        public void FillListBoxProducts(string recipeName)
        {
            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                if(recipe.Name == recipeName)
                {
                    foreach (var group in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                    {
                        listBoxProducts.Items.Add(group.Product.Name + "---" +  group.Weight + " г, ");
                    }

                    if (listBoxProducts.Items.Count != 0)
                    {
                        listBoxProducts.SelectedItem = listBoxProducts.Items[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void FillListBoxWeight(string productName)
        {
            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                if (recipe.Name == listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    foreach (var group in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                    {
                        if (group.Product.Name == productName)
                        {
                            if (group.Product.Kkal != 0)
                            {
                                listBoxWeight.Items.Add(group.Product.Kkal + ", " + group.Weight + ", " + (double)group.Product.Kkal / 100 * group.Weight);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                listBoxWeight.Items.Add(group.Product.Kkal + ", " + group.Weight + ", 0");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void FillListBoxFats(string productName)
        {
            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                if (recipe.Name == listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    foreach (var group in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                    {
                        if (group.Product.Name == productName)
                        {
                            if (group.Fats > 0)
                            {
                                listBoxFats.Items.Add(group.Fats + ", " + group.Weight + ", " + (double)group.Fats / 100 * group.Weight);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                listBoxFats.Items.Add(group.Fats + ", " + group.Weight + ", 0");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void FillListBoxSquirrels(string productName)
        {
            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                if (recipe.Name == listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    foreach (var group in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                    {
                        if (group.Product.Name == productName)
                        {
                            if (group.Squirrels > 0)
                            {
                                listBoxSquirrels.Items.Add(group.Squirrels + ", " + group.Weight + ", " + (double)group.Squirrels / 100 * group.Weight);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                listBoxSquirrels.Items.Add(group.Squirrels + ", " + group.Weight + ", 0");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void FillListBoxCarbohydrates(string productName)
        {
            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                if (recipe.Name == listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    foreach (var group in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                    {
                        if (group.Product.Name == productName)
                        {
                            if (group.Carbohydrates > 0)
                            {
                                listBoxCarbohydrates.Items.Add(group.Carbohydrates + ", " + group.Weight + ", " + (double)group.Carbohydrates / 100 * group.Weight);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                listBoxCarbohydrates.Items.Add(group.Carbohydrates + ", " + group.Weight + ", 0");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void FillListBoxDecription(string recipeName)
        {
            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                if (recipe.Name == recipeName)
                {
                    listBoxDecription.Items.Add(recipe.Description);

                    if (listBoxDecription.Items.Count != 0)
                    {
                        listBoxDecription.SelectedItem = listBoxProducts.Items[0];
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void listBoxRecepts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBoxProducts.Items.Clear();

            FillListBoxProducts(listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString());

            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                double sumkkal = 0;
                foreach (var recipeGroup in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                {
                    sumkkal += (double)recipeGroup.Product.Kkal / 100 * recipeGroup.Weight;
                }
                if (recipe.Name == listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    label4.Text = "ККал блюда: " + sumkkal + " Kkal";
                }

                double sumsq = 0;
                foreach (var recipeGroup in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                {
                    sumsq += (double)recipeGroup.Squirrels / 100 * recipeGroup.Weight;
                }
                if (recipe.Name == listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    label10.Text = "Всего: " + sumsq + " г";
                }

                double sumfats = 0;
                foreach (var recipeGroup in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                {
                    sumfats += (double)recipeGroup.Fats / 100 * recipeGroup.Weight;
                }
                if (recipe.Name == listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    label11.Text = "Всего: " + sumfats + " г";
                }

                double sumcarb = 0;
                foreach (var recipeGroup in recipe.RecipeGroups)
                {
                    sumcarb += (double)recipeGroup.Carbohydrates / 100 * recipeGroup.Weight;
                }
                if (recipe.Name == listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    label12.Text = "Всего: " + sumcarb + " г";
                }

            }

            listBoxDecription.Items.Clear();

            FillListBoxDecription(listBoxRecepts.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }

        private void listBoxProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBoxWeight.Items.Clear();

            FillListBoxWeight(listBoxProducts.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-')[0]);

            listBoxFats.Items.Clear();

            FillListBoxFats(listBoxProducts.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-')[0]);

            listBoxSquirrels.Items.Clear();

            FillListBoxSquirrels(listBoxProducts.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-')[0]);

            listBoxCarbohydrates.Items.Clear();

            FillListBoxCarbohydrates(listBoxProducts.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-')[0]);
        }

    }
}
```

Класс Recipe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Recept.Domain
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public Guid ID { get; private set; }
        public List<RecipeGroup> RecipeGroups { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }

        public Recipe(string name, Guid id, List<RecipeGroup> recipeeGroups, string description)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(description));

            ID = id;
            RecipeGroups = recipeeGroups;
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
        }


    }
}
```

Класс Product:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Recept.Domain
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Kkal { get; private set; }

        public Product(string name, int kkal)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

            if (kkal < 0) throw new ArgumentException();

            Name = name;
            Kkal = kkal;

        }   
    }
}
```

Класс RecipeGroup:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Recept.Domain 
{
    public class RecipeGroup
    {
        public Product Product { get; private set; }
        public int Weight { get; private set; }
        public int Squirrels { get; private set; }
        public int Fats { get; private set; }
        public int Carbohydrates { get; private set; }


        public RecipeGroup(Product product, int weight, int squirrels, int fats, int carbohydrates)
        {
            if (weight < 0) throw new ArgumentException();
            if (squirrels < 0) throw new ArgumentException();
            if (fats < 0) throw new ArgumentException();
            if (carbohydrates < 0) throw new ArgumentException();

            Product = product;
            Weight = weight;
            Squirrels = squirrels;
            Fats = fats;
            Carbohydrates = carbohydrates;
        }
    }   

}
```

Класс CompletedReceipes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Recept.Domain
{
    public static class CompletedReceipes
    {
        public static Recipe FirstRecipe()
        {
            Product chickenroll = new Product("Рулет куриный", 310);
            Product bulgarianpepper = new Product("Перец болгарский", 26);
            Product russiancheese = new Product("Сыр российский", 362);
            Product salad = new Product("Салат", 12);
            Product crackers = new Product("Сухарики", 336);
            Product mayonnaise = new Product("Майонез", 627);
            Product boiledegg = new Product("Яйцо вареное", 160);
            Product mustard = new Product("Горчица", 142);

            RecipeGroup chickenrollGroup = new RecipeGroup(chickenroll, 200, 16, 26, 0);
            RecipeGroup bulgarianpepperGroup = new RecipeGroup(bulgarianpepper, 150, 1, 0, 5);
            RecipeGroup russiancheeseGroup = new RecipeGroup(russiancheese, 50, 23, 30, 1);
            RecipeGroup saladGroup = new RecipeGroup(salad, 50, 1, 1, 2);
            RecipeGroup crackersGroup = new RecipeGroup(crackers, 50, 16, 1, 70);
            RecipeGroup mayonnaiseGroup = new RecipeGroup(mayonnaise, 40, 3, 68, 5);
            RecipeGroup boiledeggGroup = new RecipeGroup(boiledegg, 110, 12, 11, 1);
            RecipeGroup mustardGroup = new RecipeGroup(mustard, 4, 29, 29, 29);

            List<RecipeGroup> recipeGroups1 = new List<RecipeGroup>() { chickenrollGroup, bulgarianpepperGroup, russiancheeseGroup, saladGroup, crackersGroup, mayonnaiseGroup, boiledeggGroup, mustardGroup };


            Recipe recipe1 = new Recipe("Салат 'Цезарь с курицей' ", Guid.NewGuid(), recipeGroups1, "http://www.calorizator.ru/recipe/7643");

            return recipe1;
        }

        public static Recipe SecondRecipe()
        {
            Product bananas = new Product("Банананы", 89);
            Product sugar = new Product("Сахар", 398);
            Product flour = new Product("Мука пшеничная", 342);
            Product salt = new Product("Соль", 0);
            Product bakingpowder = new Product("Разрыхлитель теста", 86);

            RecipeGroup bananasGroup = new RecipeGroup(bananas, 330, 1, 1, 22);
            RecipeGroup sugarGroup = new RecipeGroup(sugar, 50, 0, 0, 100);
            RecipeGroup flourGroup = new RecipeGroup(flour, 100, 10, 1, 75);
            RecipeGroup saltGroup = new RecipeGroup(salt, 2, 0, 0, 0);
            RecipeGroup bakingpowderGroup = new RecipeGroup(bakingpowder, 7, 14, 0, 29);

            List<RecipeGroup> recipeGroups2 = new List<RecipeGroup>() { bananasGroup, sugarGroup, flourGroup, saltGroup, bakingpowderGroup };

            Recipe recipe2 = new Recipe("Банановые оладушки", Guid.NewGuid(), recipeGroups2, "http://www.calorizator.ru/recipes/40394");

            return recipe2;
        }

        public static Recipe ThirdRecipe()
        {
            Product strawberry = new Product("Клубника", 41);
            Product yogurt = new Product("Йогурт натуральный 2%", 60);
            Product sugar = new Product("Сахар", 398);
            Product lemon = new Product("Лимон", 16);
            Product ice = new Product("Лед колотый", 0);

            RecipeGroup strawberryGroup = new RecipeGroup(strawberry, 800, 1, 1, 8);
            RecipeGroup yogurtGroup = new RecipeGroup(yogurt, 500, 4, 2, 6);
            RecipeGroup sugarGroup = new RecipeGroup(sugar, 50, 0, 0, 100);
            RecipeGroup lemonGroup = new RecipeGroup(lemon, 43, 2, 1, 4);
            RecipeGroup iceGroup = new RecipeGroup(ice, 20, 0, 0, 0);

            List<RecipeGroup> recipeGroups3 = new List<RecipeGroup>() { strawberryGroup, yogurtGroup, sugarGroup, lemonGroup, iceGroup };

            Recipe recipe3 = new Recipe("Клубничный смузи", Guid.NewGuid(), recipeGroups3, "http://www.calorizator.ru/recipes/35471");

            return recipe3;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну а в чем проблема то? Вы выделенные в ListBox элементы не можете найти или что не получается?

Comment: Я вообще не могу понять, как это прописать, как сделать так, чтобы выбирались несколько рецептов и суммировалась их калорийность.

Comment: `как сделать так, чтобы выбирались несколько рецептов`- [Multi selection list box in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2059957/312041) - я нашел это за три секунды, почему вы не нашли? Вы не искали? Поясните, что вы сами сделали, чтобы решить свою задачу?